# Prevent Office 365 from requesting phone number

Tags: microsoft-office, active-directory, authentication, office365

I've been using Office 365 (federated against my domain) for several months. 
Recently when I login to http://portal.office.com, the site complains I need to `Add information to your account so you don't lose access if you ever forget your password`:

[image: Don't lose access to your account]

Clicking `Set it up now` takes me to this screen:

[image: Office 365 Verify Phone]

> <sup>To make sure you can reset your password,
>   we need to collect some into so we can verify who you are. 
>   We won't use this to spam you – just to keep your account more secure. 
>   You'll need to set up at least 1 of the options below.  ...</sup>

### Question

**How do I disable this prompt?**  My account is federated to my domain, so if I forgot my password I would contact my Domain Admin, not Microsoft.

### Update

I am *not* the Domain Admin, but I've checked with him and he hasn't intentionally set any configuration on my account to force this verification behavior.

Comment: Are you the domain admin? If so, I'd recommend posting this on Serverfault. If not, I'd recommend talking to the Domain Admin. I don't think it's *completely* off topic for Super User, but I hope that points you in a better direction.

Comment: Can I move it to server fault myself, or does it need to be "vote to move"d?

Comment: If you are the Domain Admin, you can choose to Close->Off Topic->Another Site->Server Fault. I'd edit the question to mention your role. If you are NOT the Domain Admin, then Server Fault will not take the question.

Comment: How you get rid of this prompt is one of two ways.  You either as the Administrator remove the requirement to do so or you asked the administrator to remove the requirement. If the prompt is for the underline Office 365 account itself and not the email account to the domain the requirement was set by Microsoft.  I can't tell from the screenshot though.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm not sure what you mean by `the underline Office 365 account itself.`  The prompt is from logging in with my `@company.com` address.

Answer (score 2):

This option comes up when Self Service Password Reset has been enabled. In order to authenticate when you want to reset your password, you'll need to use one of the authentication options you are being asked to provide. It's a good thing.